# Navigate between pages with different size UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I am new making app with UWP, I was looking for a solution to this but I can not find something. My problem is when a changes from a page1 with a dimension  500 x 500 to page2 with a dimension 1000 x 800, of the second page just can be view a part. My questions are:

1. Do all the pages have to be the same sizes?
2. If I can have different sizes, how can a do it ?
3. Do you know an article that talks about the sizes of the pages in UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages themselves display in a Frame which in turn either displays in a container or in the Window. The page does not determine the size of how it is displayed. You could of course hardcode the size of the page, but that would mean there would be empty space in the app window and it would not look well.

UWP offers `AdaptiveTriggers` that allow you to modify the layout of your page depending on the size of the app window so that the app looks great with window of any size.

In case you really need to have the app window of a given size, you could do a resize of the window.

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(desiredSize);
```